# sed command to delete starting pattern match with special character in it

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have sed command that delete line when string match with starting pattern

**`sed -i "/^Data\=C\b/Id" tally.ini`**

This work correctly for patch Data=C

But I want to match path Data=C:\ and that I want to delete this line.

How can this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i  '/^Data\=C:\\/Id' tally.ini
```

Put the command in a single quoted string instead of double. 
Escape the backslash.